# Share spec files across multiCapabilities in protractor

Tags: protractor

How to share spec files across capabilities in protractor:

I tried following but rather than sharing specs its executing all the specs(Login folder contains 4 specs) across capabilities:

```
exports.config = {
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxSessions: 3,
    specs: ['./testExecution/UserManagement/Login/*.js'],
    verboseMultiSessions: true,
multiCapabilities: [
         {
          browserName : 'internet explorer',
          seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
         },
        {
          browserName : 'chrome',
          seleniumAddress: 'http://172.23.230.198:4444/wd/hub'         
        }
]
}
```

Comment: Milan, from testing perspective, you should not shard spec files across multiple browsers as then you are not testing all scripts on all browsers but randomly executing them on different browsers.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Yes agree on that, however my requirement here is spec distribution on different machines irrespective of browser.

Answer (score 0):

use `shardTestFiles:true` inside the multicapabilities object. look at below example for multicapability,

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['specs/spec1.js','specs/spec2.js']
    },
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,
        sequential: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['specs/spec4.js',
            'specs/spec5.js',
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: @Sudharshan as specified in my question I want to distribute my specs across machines thats why I mentioned spec outside of multiCapabilities.
 Some feature like share spec among capabilities.